# How can I extract IP addresses from a large text file in a clob column?

Tags: json, oracle, extract, clob

I have a column that contains large text files in a clob.  It is a json, but each file can have different key names.  How can I extract any IP address anywhere in the file regardless of what the key name is?

I've tried variations of something like this but I either get an unending return of empty rows or it completes returning nothing.

```
SELECT
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(
    REGEXP_REPLACE(json, '[^0-9.]', ' '),
    '\b(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\b',
    1,
    LEVEL
  ) AS extracted_ip
FROM
  kg_json_tst
CONNECT BY PRIOR DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE IS NOT NULL
       AND REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE(json, '[^0-9.]', ' '), '\b(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\b', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: and where is a sample of the CLOB data?

Comment: '\b(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\b' is not an ORACLE-compatible regex.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WITH mytable AS (SELECT 'This is a 192.0.0.1 test of a really powerful 10.5.23.251 address that is perfectly 4.30.1.2 reasonable' sample_text
                   FROM dual) -- testdata
SELECT sample_text,
       seq,
       SUBSTR(section,2,INSTR(section||' ',' ',2)-2) ip_address -- remove anything after it
  FROM (SELECT sample_text,
               seq,
               SUBSTR(marked,INSTR(marked,'$',1,b.seq)) section -- start with the IP address for this sequence
          FROM (SELECT sample_text,
                       REGEXP_REPLACE(sample_text,'([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})','$\1') marked
                  FROM mytable) a,
               (SELECT ROWNUM seq FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL < 100) b
         WHERE INSTR(marked,'$',1,b.seq) > 0) -- get as many rows as IP addresses in the string
```

You'd have to raise that 100 to a higher number if you could possibly get more than 100 IPs from the same CLOB. Technically this will match 500.500.500.500 which isn't a legal IP address. You could enhance the regexp to limit the first digits to 0-2 but 299.299.299.299 isn't legal either. Eventually you end up having to create a function to apply the various IP rules to really ensure you have a good IP. But for many cases I think a four-octet string is pretty much identifiable as an IP and may be good enough. Lastly, using my method you'd need to pick a marker (`$`) that isn't in your text. `CHR(19)` or something like that might be a better choice.